# Keras gets None gradient error when connecting models

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I’m trying to implement a Visual Storytelling model using Keras with a hierarchical RNN model, basically Neural Image Captioner style but over a sequence of photos with a bidirectional RNN on top of the decoder RNNs.

I implemented and tested the three parts of this model, CNN, BRNN and decoder RNN separately but got this error when trying to connect them:

> ValueError: An operation has None for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

My code are as follows:

```
#vgg16 model with the fc2 layer as output
cnn_base_model = self.cnn_model.base_model
brnn_model = self.brnn_model.model
rnn_model = self.rnn_model.model

cnn_part = TimeDistributed(cnn_base_model)

img_input = Input((self.story_length,) + self.cnn_model.input_shape, name='brnn_img_input')

extracted_feature = cnn_part(img_input)

#[None, 5, 512], a 512 length vector for each picture in the story
brnn_feature = brnn_model(extracted_feature)

#[None, 5, 25], input groundtruth word indices fed as input when training
decoder_input = Input((self.story_length, self.max_length), name='brnn_decoder_input')

decoder_outputs = []

for i in range(self.story_length):
  #separate timesteps for decoding
  decoder_input_i = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, i, :])(decoder_input)
  brnn_feature_i = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, i, :])(brnn_feature)

  #the problem persists when using Dense instead of the Lambda layers above
  #decoder_input_i = Dense(25)(Reshape((125,))(decoder_input))
  #brnn_feature_i = Dense(512)(Reshape((5 * 512,))(brnn_feature))

  decoder_output_i = rnn_model([decoder_input_i, brnn_feature_i])
  decoder_outputs.append(decoder_output_i)

decoder_output = Concatenate(axis=-2, name='brnn_decoder_output')(decoder_outputs)

self.model = Model([img_input, decoder_input], decoder_output)
```

And codes for the BRNN:

```
image_feature = Input(shape=(self.story_length, self.img_feature_dim,))
image_emb = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.lstm_size))(image_feature)

brnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(self.lstm_size, return_sequences=True), merge_mode='concat')(image_emb)
brnn_emb = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.lstm_size))(brnn)

self.model = Model(inputs=image_feature, outputs=brnn_emb)
```

And RNN:

```
#[None, 512], the vector to be decoded
initial_input = Input(shape=(self.input_dim,), name='rnn_initial_input')

#[None, 25], the groundtruth word indices fed as input when training 
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), name='rnn_decoder_inputs')

decoder_input_masking = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(decoder_inputs)
decoder_input_embeddings = Embedding(self.vocabulary_size, self.emb_size,
  embeddings_regularizer=l2(regularizer))(decoder_input_masking)
decoder_input_dropout = Dropout(.5)(decoder_input_embeddings)

initial_emb = Dense(self.emb_size,
  kernel_regularizer=l2(regularizer))(initial_input)

initial_reshape = Reshape((1, self.emb_size))(initial_emb)
initial_masking = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(initial_reshape)
initial_dropout = Dropout(.5)(initial_masking)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(self.hidden_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True,
  recurrent_regularizer=l2(regularizer),
  kernel_regularizer=l2(regularizer),
  bias_regularizer=l2(regularizer))

_, initial_hidden_h, initial_hidden_c = decoder_lstm(initial_dropout)

decoder_outputs, decoder_state_h, decoder_state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_input_dropout,
  initial_state=[initial_hidden_h, initial_hidden_c])

decoder_output_dense_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.vocabulary_size, activation='softmax',
  kernel_regularizer=l2(regularizer)))

decoder_output_dense = decoder_output_dense_layer(decoder_outputs)

self.model = Model([decoder_inputs, initial_input], decoder_output_dense)
```

I’m using `adam` as optimizer and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss.

At first I thought the problem is with the `Lambda` layers used for splitting the timesteps but the problem persists when I replaced them with `Dense` layers (which are guarantee

Comment: I have the same issue with an encoder-decoder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it turned out I was suppose to build the layers (in my custom layer or model) in the **init**() like so:

````
self.lstm_custom_1 = keras.layers.LSTM(128,batch_input_shape=batch_input_shape, return_sequences=False,stateful=True)
self.lstm_custom_1.build(batch_input_shape)

self.dense_custom_1 = keras.layers.Dense(32,  activation = 'relu')
self.dense_custom_1.build(input_shape=(batch_size, 128))```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually with the Embedding layer, I think. Gradients can't pass through an Embedding layer, so unless it's the first layer in the model it won't work.